# Is there a consistent axiomatic system where $1+1 = 2$, $2 \not = 1+1$?

Tags: axioms

Is it possible to create a consistent axiomatic system where $1+1 = 2$,  $2 \not = 1+1$?

Comment: I do not know what you mean with consistent, but my first question is: what is $2$ in your system? If $2$ is $1+1$, then is your statement valid only for $2$ or all possible $1+1+...+1$ (is $+$ associative?) ?Etc...etc... :)

Comment: In other words, there will be $a$ and $b$ such that $a=b$ but $b\neq a$? I am curious to know your definition of "$=$".

Comment: This of course depends on the logic. In first-order logic with equality, it's obviously impossible. In first-order logic *wihout* equality (with = being treated as a nonlogical relation symbol), it's equally obvious that it's possible.

Comment: @O.L. Yes, that's what I had in mind. I only have a basic grasp of maths, but I think it boils down to generalising "=" in an abstract way, analagous to the way the addition operator was generalised as a binary operator of a group.

Comment: Sure, because $1,2,+,=,\neq$ are all just symbols. However, we almost always use the symbol "=" to be an equivalence relationship, so if $X=Y$ then $Y=X$. But that is convention - you can make up whatever you want. Would it be useful? Probably not, and certainly not with this notation.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Thanks for the informative comment.

Answer (score 4):

Equality is an equivalence relation, so it satisfies the following three necessary conditions:

1. Reflexivity, $a = a$;
2. Symmetry, $a = b \implies b = a$;
3. Transitivity $a = b, b = c \implies a = c$.

These properties hold *regardless* of the math going on on either side of the relation. So you can define $+$ to be standard real addition, or addition modulo $p$, or whatever. If you make the statement $ 1 + 1 = 2$ within whatsoever arithmetical system you so desire, then by using $=$, you are making a claim that necessarily carries these properties, so $2 = 1+1$, always.

You could, however, define a relation that is *not* an equivalence relation such that $1 + 1 \sim 2$, but $2 \not\sim 1+1$.

For example, $\textrm{C} + \textrm{O}_2 \to \textrm{CO}_2$, but $\textrm{CO}_2 \not\to \textrm{C} + \textrm{O}_2$, leading to global warming.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to intend that we're allowed to redefine "$+$" and "$=$" to mean whatever we want. Then certainly we can have $1+1=2$ and $2 \neq 1+1$: for example, we could interpret "$+$" to mean $-$ and "$=$" to mean $<$.

Answer (score 0):

You could but firstly the $+$ and $=$ ect. would have to hold different functions and/or, secondly you could have an axiom that for instance works with the principles of the time arrow (direction of time) and the law of entropy in a dynamic system, which would state that once an operation has been carried out then it cannot be reversed or broken down into its original constituents. i.e. as per your example $1+1=2$, $2\not=1+1$

P.S. I know that I used physics examples but that is for two good reasons, firstly it is easier to picture, secondly (more importantly) the examples have were originally derived from mathematical equations.